# Is it possible to control the scroll position of an Animated.Scrollview in react-native with the Animated API?

Tags: react-native, react-native-scrollview

I'm trying to manually control the deceleration of an `Animated.ScrollView` after the user releases their finger. I have found plenty of resources on setting an animated value to the position of a scrollview but nothing about tying the position of the scrollview to an animated value. Is it possible to control the scrollview in the way I'm describing?